# Typescript give "string" type instead of "string | null " - vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Typescript infer the wrong type

I expect "something" will have a type of `"string |null"` , but vscode give `"string"` instead

I am using typescript 3.3

```
interface S {
 // wrong expectation : "something" has type of string
 something : string | null
}
```

[screenshot vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfCHM.png)

Comment: Did you enable null strict checks?

Comment: no i didn't . i used the react-native shipped typescript. do you have an idea how can i overwrite the compile option? i am using 0.58.4

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Nail Achmedzhanov 's comment under the original question.

it was because "null strict checks" is set to false.

set to true should solved my problem. (Finding way to overwrite react-native typescript setting)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is by the definition.

> By default null and undefined are **subtypes of all other types**. That means you can assign null and undefined to something like number.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: but i am sure typescript will still infer "string | null" in my case (coz i am able to do this in another project"